# Binding errors coming from under hood

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

Trying to use grouping in `DataGrid` and for no reasons getting those binding errors (they are not belong to my code, nor I see a way to deal with them):

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=AreRowDetailsFrozen; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridDetailsPresenter' (Name=''); target property is 'SelectiveScrollingOrientation' (type 'SelectiveScrollingOrientation')

and

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=HeadersVisibility; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridRowHeader' (Name=''); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')

They appears for **each row** in `DataGrid`. This bugs me alot!

To reproduce the problem I made a small project

```
public class MyItem
{
    public string A { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public List<MyItem> List { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        List = new List<MyItem>(new[] { new MyItem() });
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

xaml

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding List}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding A}" Header="A"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="GroupItem">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="GroupItem">
                                <!-- anything or nothing here -->
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
        </GroupStyle>
    </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Some observations:

- without `DataGrid.GroupStyle` there are no errors;
- with `AutoGenerateColumns = true` there are no errors;
- without binding (setting `DataGrid.ItemsSource` directly) there are no errors.

Only combination of opposite to those 3 conditions will start spamming `Output` window with above messages.

What should I do? I can't ignore errors, nor I see a way to fix them.

Googling around wasn't really helpful, to example, [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3893990/1997232) was called a bug, I tried to apply its workarounds, but none works for me.

P.S.: discovering such bugs at first attempt to use `DataGrid` is very demotivating.

---

Trying to deal with second error.

```
<DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRowHeader">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
```

But error still

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=HeadersVisibility; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridRowHeader' (Name=''); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')

Answer (score 4):

Was *playing* with control templates and after changing one for `DataGridRow` errors are gone!

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridRow">
                    <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}" Name="DGR_Border" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                            <DataGridCellsPresenter ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsControl.ItemsPanel}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

I removed `DataGridDetailsPresenter` and `DataGridRowHeader` from default template, because I will not use them.

---

I got one more error

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=NewItemMargin; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridRow' (Name=''); target property is 'Margin' (type 'Thickness')

which I fix by adding `Margin` setter into `DataGrid.RowStyle`

```
<Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
```

It seems all of such errors can be fixed by re-factoring default templates.

Comment: thanks, guy! after searched lots of 'workaround' through googling, only your way works!

Comment: Worked for me too.  Thanks!

Comment: It seems to suppress part of the problem, but doesn't really solve it. I have a GroupStyle and an ICollectionView.Filter... since I got this error they don't work anymore! Unfortunately, after implementing your solution, they still don't work

Answer (score 0):

Firs of all thanks Sinatr for the problem analysis and the solution, which almost worked for me.
I did have the same problem with the DataGrid Control. Apart from the binding errors in the output there was a slight displacement of the new item row (in my case the DataRowMargin was off by two DIPs).

[DataGridRow invalid margin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Te0I.png)

The whole issue is caused by a style trigger activated when the IsNewItemProperty equals true, the DataGridRow is not getting the proper margin values. The answer from Sinatr did fix the binding issue but the wrong margin was still used. This is the styling that removed the binding errors and set the correct margin.

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}" Name="DGR_Border" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                        <DataGridCellsPresenter ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsControl.ItemsPanel}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsNewItem" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1,0,0,0"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```