# Binding issues in ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am getting issues w.r.t binding for the ListView Item. The issue is:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with
>   reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor,
>   AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl',
>   AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=VerticalContentAlignment;
>   DataItem=null; target element is 'ListViewItem' (Name=''); target
>   property is 'VerticalContentAlignment' (type 'VerticalAlignment')
>
> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with
>   reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor,
>   AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl',
>   AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=HorizontalContentAlignment;
>   DataItem=null; target element is 'ListViewItem' (Name=''); target
>   property is 'HorizontalContentAlignment' (type 'HorizontalAlignment')

I have a ListView, and have set the ItemContainerStyle, still I am getting the same issue. Please help

```
<ListView Width="Auto" Height="1" Name="ListViewDetails" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding DetailsObservableCollection}">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Where do you get this errors? Is this a compile error or do you see it in the debug output window? I am not able to reproduce this with your code.

Comment: Where is your datacontext defined?

Comment: Replace `ListView.ItemContainerStyle` with `ListView.Resources`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF DataBinding Error: Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893990/wpf-databinding-error-cannot-find-source-for-binding-with-reference-relativeso)

Comment: That error indicates a problem with a relative-source binding, but your XAML doesn't show us any such bindings...

Comment: I have a checkbox, and on check/uncheck command of the checkbox, the listview items are getting loaded. Code for checkbox is something like this,                                                                                     <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding ...}"                                      Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.CheckboxChecked}"/>  And I am getting the issue which I mentioned above in the output window. So I'm not able to understand why the binding issues are observed.

Comment: I've encountered similar behavior with `ComboBoxItem` when it was not inserted into the logical tree (it was contained inside a `CompositeCollection`). Does your `DetailsObservableCollection` contain any `ListViewItem` by any chance? Or can you think of any place in your code where you used `ListViewItem` not directly inside `ListView`?

Comment: @PieterWitvoet I don't think that the problem comes from improper usage of relative-source bindings by OP. The bindings mentioned in the error messages are set in the default (implicit) style for `ListViewItem` - you can observe these exact messages when you create a window with a single `ListViewItem` as it's content.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your error. It works okay. It seems to me that you have some incorrect initializations at properties at view model. See the work example of MVVM ListView .

**Model:**

```
 public class Person
 {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public bool IsClickable { get; set; }
 }
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class MainWindowViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {        
        private ObservableCollection<Person> _persons=new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons
        {
            get
            {
                return _persons=GetData();
            }
            set
            {
                _persons = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Persons");
            }
        }        

        public ObservableCollection<Person> GetData()
        {
             myDataList.Add(new Person() { ID = 1, Name = "Person1", Author = "Author1", Price = "6.7 TL", Catalog = "IT", IsClickable=true});
             myDataList.Add(new Person() { ID = 2, Name = "Person2", Author = "Author2", Price = "9.7 TL", Catalog = "IT", IsClickable = false});
             myDataList.Add(new Person() { ID = 3, Name = "Person3", Author = "Author3", Price = "11.7 TL", Catalog = "IT", IsClickable = true});
             myDataList.Add(new Person() { ID = 2, Name = "Person4", Author = "Author2", Price = "9.7 TL", Catalog = "IT", IsClickable = true});
             myDataList.Add(new Person() { ID = 3, Name = "Person5", Author = "Author3", Price = "11.7 TL", Catalog = "IT", IsClickable = false});
            if (myDataList.Count > 0)
            {
                return myDataList;
            }
            else
                return null;
        }

        RelayCommand _clickCommand = null;
        public ICommand SomeClickCommand
        {
           get
           {
              if (_clickCommand == null)
                {
                   _clickCommand = new RelayCommand((p) => OnClick(p), (p) => CanClick(p));
                }

            return _clickCommand;
           }
        }

        private bool CanClick(object obj)
        {
           return true;
        }

        private void OnClick(object obj)
        {
           MessageBox.Show("You clicked:)");
        }

        #region OnPropertyChanged
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("propertyName"));
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

**View with your features:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        ...
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.ViewModel"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="550" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="mainWindowViewModel"/>
    </Window.Resources>
   <StackPanel DataContext="{StaticResource mainWindowViewModel}">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <WrapPanel>                        
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Background="LightGreen" Margin="1"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Author}" Background="LightCyan" Margin="1"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TimeGap}" Background="LightCoral" Margin="1"/>                        
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsClickable}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Command="{Binding DataContext.SomeClickCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type StackPanel}}}"  Margin="1"/>

                </WrapPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>            
    </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Pay attention that I've binded `DataContext` to `StackPanel`. So I should type that `StackPanel` as `AncestorType`:

```
 <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsClickable}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Command="{Binding DataContext.SomeClickCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type StackPanel}}}"  Margin="1"/>
```

Comment: I have a checkbox, and on check/uncheck command of the checkbox, the listview items are getting loaded. Code for checkbox is something like this,                                                                                     <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding ...}"                                      Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.CheckboxChecked}"/>  And I am getting the issue which I mentioned above in the output window. So I'm not able to understand why the binding issues are observed.

Comment: @NisargaNagaraj  you can accept my reply as an answer if it helps to you:).